# C - how to convert a pointer in an array to an index?

Tags: c, pointers, indexing, pointer-arithmetic

In the many search functions of C (bsearch comes to mind) if a result is found, a pointer to the spot in the array is returned. How can I convert this pointer to the index in the array that was searched (using pointer arithmetic, i assume).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
ptrdiff_t index = pointer_found - array_name;
```

Comment: and if the arrays are type void, i get a compile warning. so it doesn't know how to do the subtraction correctly. i ended up converting both to (char *), subtracting, then dividing by the size of an element. i'm not sure if that works, though

Comment: There is no array of type `void`, but there is a pointer of type `void`.

Comment: @hatorade cast the pointer to the type of the array elements. For example: `int arr[..]; void* p = &arr[1]; size_t index = (int*)p - arr;`

Comment: why do you use `size_t` and not `ptrdiff_t`?