# Binary search with a vector

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search

I have a sorted vector V and I want to binary search the smallest index i for which V[i] <= target. This is my current attempt but it isn't working right.

```
int hi= L;
int lo= 1;
int mid  = (hi+lo)/2;
while (hi>lo+1){
    if (V[mid]>=target) hi=mid;
    else lo= mid;
    mid=(hi+lo)/2;
}
```

Comment: why rewrite binary_search algorithm? can't just use lower_bound,upper_bound ?

Comment: This seems exactly like your [previous now deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029382/binary-search-against-a-vector-of-pairs) ? Did you need to make a new one?

Comment: @billz It doesn't work for this particular question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a "useful" C++ binary search algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446296/where-can-i-get-a-useful-c-binary-search-algorithm)

Comment: [here you go](http://bit.ly/146U7DG)

Comment: @A.H. My question is a little different so Google doesn't quite help

Comment: @AgainstASicilian wikipedia has a sample that works with vectors

Comment: @A.H. The problem is my boundary condition is different

Comment: @Borgleader I had tried lower_bound(P.begin(), P.end(), target, [](pair<int,int> lhs, int rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs; }); and that didn't work. Error error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::pair<int, int>*, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > >' to 'int' in assignment

Comment: @AgainstASicilian you need for a vector of pairs ? What is `V[mid]` ?

Comment: @P0W I used vector in question because easier to word but since learning that lower_bound exists I want to use it for pair version

Comment: @AgainstASicilian I don't know what you're doing but I've successfully searched an element in a vector of pairs using the answer from that question.

Comment: @Borgleader Are you setting it into a variable? When I do it it throws error. How are you using it precisely. I am trying to get the index

Comment: @AgainstASicilian What exactly do you mean by "setting it to a variable"

Comment: @Borgleader I want to find int smallest_index = binary_search, that version does not seem to do that

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Once you have the iterator to the element getting the index is trivial.

Comment: I think maybe I have miscommunicated. I want the index that corresponds to the pair where the first element is the smallest possible that is <= target

Comment: also it is not trivial, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711653/c-how-to-convert-a-pointer-in-an-array-to-an-index but this doesn't work here by just subtracting P, so it is harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   auto s=v.begin();
   auto e=v.end();
   auto L = std::distance(s, e);

  while (L > 0)
{
  auto half = L/2;
  auto mid = s;
  std::advance(mid, half);
  if (*mid < target)
    {
      s = mid;
      ++s;
      L = L - half - 1;
    }
  else
    L = half;
}
  //s is your element !
```

Or why can't you use lower_bound for `< target` search :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

typedef std::pair<int,int> mypair;

struct comp_pairs
{
   bool operator()( const mypair lhs, 
                    const int& rhs ) const 
   { return lhs.first < rhs; }
   bool operator()( const int& lhs, 
                    const mypair& rhs ) const 
   { return lhs<rhs.first; }
};

int main()        
{

std::vector<mypair> V;
V.push_back(std::make_pair(2,9));
V.push_back(std::make_pair(3,8));
V.push_back(std::make_pair(4,7));
V.push_back(std::make_pair(5,6));

int target =4;
  auto pos=std::lower_bound(V.begin(),V.end(),target,comp_pairs());

std::cout << "Position " << (pos- V.begin()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Neither of these work, last one doesn't know what Val is either, first half returns wrong value

Comment: Is this something you assign? technically my vector is a vector of pairs and I am comparing first-elements, is it mid = lower_bound(P.begin(), P.end(), target, [](pair<int,int> lhs, pair<int,int> rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; }); ?